# How can I merge two blob audio and video and get one single video blob object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I had use but it always return video  without audio

```
var newBlob = new Blob([video_blob, audio_blob], "video/mp4");
```

Comment: have you checked this question?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob
https://stackoverflow.com/users/977809/nkron se

Comment: I had checked that's why I mentioned code above

Answer (score 0):

You can't just merge video and audio streams.

The process of joining video and audio streams is called muxing. I've found a library which seems to do just that but on node.js https://github.com/videojs/mux.js/
There is also https://github.com/samirkumardas/jmuxer which seems to be exactly what you need.

Maybe you could look for a player that supports getting video and audio as separate blobs. But video and audio might get out of sync then.

Comment: I have blob url

Comment: Can you specify what are you trying to achieve? From your question I've assumed you use this blob to playback audio/video content. Am I right?

Comment: I want to screen record with microphone, but I don't find the solutions so i had done seperately screen reocrd and audio record so I want to merge both blob and getting one sigle blob

Comment: I think it would be great to add some details into your question (eg. what are you trying to do). Another thing is how do you verify if you don't get audio?